# sql server status change time

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
THENUMBER       NUMBER      SYSMODTIME              TYPE
ACTIM2816332    IM0540202   2014-11-18 09:17:53.000 Closed
ACTIM2806050    IM0540202   2014-11-13 15:11:29.000 Update
ACTIM2806051    IM0540202   2014-11-13 15:11:29.000 External Vendor Assignment
ACTIM2806049    IM0540202   2014-11-13 15:11:29.000 Status Change
ACTIM2806046    IM0540202   2014-11-13 15:10:34.000 Assignment
ACTIM2804167    IM0540202   2014-11-13 09:31:12.000 Status Change
ACTIM2804166    IM0540202   2014-11-13 09:31:12.000 Assignment
ACTIM2802130    IM0540202   2014-11-12 17:09:57.000 Open
```

Could You please help me to create a select to calculate time difference between type change from open to close ?

I need to be a universal for different NUMBER.

Comment: What do you want the difference in? minutes, hours, days etc?

Comment: thanks you very much, how about time difference between type change from open to assignment ?

Comment: This would involve a sub query within the datediff as it would be a min(time) for the open and then a select time from table where type = open group by number, or something along those lines. better to ask that seperatly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Minutes**

```
SELECT NUMBER, MAX([SYSMODTIME]) AS Closed, MIN([SYSMODTIME]) AS Open,
(DATEDIFF (mi, MAX([LoginDateTime]), MIN([SYSMODTIME]))) AS [datediff]
FROM table
GROUP BY NUMBER
```

**Hours**

```
SELECT NUMBER, MAX([SYSMODTIME]) AS Closed, MIN([SYSMODTIME]) AS Open,
(DATEDIFF (hh, MAX([LoginDateTime]), MIN([SYSMODTIME]))) AS [datediff]
FROM table
GROUP BY NUMBER
```